# Get a value from a hidden input field in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which is auto-generated with data from the  database and created using jquery. This is created using the  following tr variable which is appended to the main tbody : 
Below is my code :

```
var list = " <tr id='order_no_tr'><td id='order_no_td" + item.documentno + "'>" + item.documentno + "</td><td>" + item.progressstatus + "</td><td>" + newDate + "</td>\n\
                                <td><button type='button' id='cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' class='btn btn-default btn-sm cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' >Confirm Received</button>\n\
        <input type='hidden' name='order_no_txt' id='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + "' value='" + item.c_order_id + "' class='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + " btn btn-primary'/>\n\
        </td></tr>";
$("#order_no_tbody").append(list);
$("#order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```

Now I want to get the value of the html input name called order_no_txt, I have tried accessing it through the following function but it fails :

```
$("#order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```

Please advise on how I can achieve this?

Comment: My advice is to start by not fetching your data but creating a sample `<table>` with fake data in it, and see if your function that handle the click works.

Answer (score 1):

Since the hidden element is sibling of button, you can use the relationship to traverse up to element using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and fetch its value using [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$("#order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var a = $(this).next(':hidden').val();
            //Following can also be used
            //$(this).closest('td').find(':hidden').val()
    alert(a);
});
```

References

- [:hidden Selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

You should learn [**event delegation**](https://api.jquery.com/val/), for dynamically created elements.

---

As per comment *The click only works for the first record and fails for the others.*, **Identifiers must be unique.** It seems you are reusing `order_no_tr` as ID multiple time so that's the expected behaviour.

Change

```
$("#order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
});
```

To

```
$(".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id).on("click", function() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I have a new issue, The click only works for the  first record and fails for the  others. How can I resolve this? I presume the  problem has to be with the  on click function.

Comment: @user689017, Update answer learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)